# Split layout into two?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, performance

I want to split my fragment into two relative layout's, and a TabLayout on top. My problem is that the tab layout overlaps with the top RelativeLayout, making it look like less than 50%:

**How I want it to look. Both sections should take up 50% NOT INCLUDING THE TAB**
[image]

Currently, the tab is part of the top Relative Layout's 50%, and so the bottom section looks larger. How can I fix this? Here is the XML:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#3ed682">

        ...

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ae25fd">
        ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I split the two sections evenly despite my tab layout at the top?

Comment: Put your tab layout on top, then a vertical linear layout under the tab layout and then two relative layouts inside of the linear layout each with a layout_weight of 1.

Comment: @LikeWhiteOnRice I have that, but the tab layout is not added in the fragment's XML, it is added in the MainActivity's XML.

Comment: What does your ViewPager look like in your activities XML?  It should have a height of 0dp and your TabLayout should have a height of wrap_content.

Comment: @LikeWhiteOnRice    `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />`

Comment: In your relative layouts try `android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 1):

Change your ViewPager in activity layout

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```